# Angular Error: $parse:ueoe Unexpected End of Expression with EJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ejs, angularjs-ng-init

I'm getting unexpected End of expression error when I pass nodejs data to to ng-init. I'm confident I'm doing it right however I'm getting the error message above

I call ng-init like so:

```
<body id="myPage" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="arrCtrl" ng-init="items = <%- JSON.stringify(myitems) %>">
```

and the error is here

```
Unexpected end of expression: items = [{
```

Thus when I run

```
{{items}}
```

It'll display as is.

I also went ahead and declared my module in my script tag just in case like so

```
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('arrCtrl', function(){
            console.log("Controller loaded");
        });

    </script>
```

I looked everywhere and no one seemed to have solved this issue.

Comment: Are you mixing server side with client side? You should fetch the items from the server and resolve it to the controller, or use inject `$http` to the dependencies list of the controller and make an ajax request. Also `JSON.stringify` returns string, not json

Comment: Yea im mixing both. I tried fetching the items from the controller, however I keep getting syntax errors. However those errors stop when I fetch from ng-init